# Adding plain text to a tab-actionbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I currently have a `ViewPager` with 3 Fragments to scroll around horizontally and I use the `ActionBar` to display in which Tab I'm currently at. You can also change the pages via clicking on the elements in the `ActionBar`.

This works flawlessly, but my Problem is that I need some additional text on the right corner of the `ActionBar` (or at least it would be very nice).

Is there any possibility to add a `TextView` (or something else which can display plain text) on an `ActionBar` with `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` or do I need to implement the Tab-behaviour myself (with a custom Layout for the ActionBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution which may not be perfect but is sufficient for me:

I used an Action Bar Item with the attribute `android:showAsAction="always"` and used it like a `TextView` (I didn't implement any onClick action).

```
MenuItem mItem = null;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    mItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item);
    return true;
}
```

Now i can change the text dynamically with `mItem.setTitle(R.string.item_text);`

Hopefully I could've helped somebody else with this question/answer.